# How do I open .html files and have them work with my external CSS and Javascript files on iPad? (iPad Mini 2, iOS 12.4.3)

Tags: ios, ipad, javascript, html, css

I am really frustrated here. I really would like this to work on my iPad, because it's for an important project, but no matter what I do, my html files refuse to connect to my .css files, my .js files, and any multimedia I have. Meanwhile, my site works like a charm on my Kindle Fire and all computers I've tried it on. Furthermore, I can't even open up my html files in a web browser, but when I open them in the default iOS file manager, they show up with no javascript, no css, and no multimedia.

Comment: What are you using to write your code? iOS's file system doesn't work like a traditional computer's. In order to accomplish what you are seeking to do, you likely need to use an IDE built for iOS such as [GoCoEdit](https://gocoedit.app/) or [Panic Code Editor](https://panic.com/code-editor/) that has its own file staging and built-in browser.